# Shortening instead of butter

Tags: baking

I have no butter for my chocolate chip cookies. What can I use instead? And how much? My cookies calls for one cup of butter.

Comment: There are cookies made with oil, here are two examples: http://www.averiecooks.com/2014/03/the-best-soft-and-chewy-coconut-oil-chocolate-chip-cookies.html and here http://www.twopeasandtheirpod.com/chewy-coconut-oatmeal-cookies/

Comment: And here is some information from a previous post about rising/leavening. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15091/how-does-replacing-some-butter-with-shortening-affect-rising-leavening-in-cook?rq=1

Comment: @padma calling these "made with oil" is borderline misleading, since coconut oil at (part of what we would consider) room temperature is solid and will behave more like shortening than like oil...

Answer (score 1):

Butter and shortening can generally be substituted for each other in cookie recipes if you keep a few things in mind: Since butter does contain water and less fat than shortening, you'll need to use more of it as a substitution. Also keep in the mind that the textures and shapes of the cookies will be different due to moisture content and melting points.