# Runny Cookie Dough

Tags: baking, cookies, consistency

## Roasted Peanut Cookies

> *It is raining outside and the water drops are pelting my window.
> Warmed some milk and gathered some pots to bake some cookies*

1. Flour (1 1/2 cups)
2. White & Brown Sugar (1/2 cups)
3. Eggs (2)
4. Milk (1/4 cups)
5. Vegetable Oil (3 1/3 oz)
6. Roasted Peanuts (3 1/3 oz)
7. Baking Powder (1 teaspoon)

So I preheated the oven to 150<sup>o</sup>. Mixed the flour, sugar, egg, milk, oil and baking powder in a pot. To the brown mixture, I added the grounded peanuts and mixed them evenly. The dough appeared runny and wouldn't dry up even with the addition of more flour. I placed medium sized blobs of this "paste" on the baking tray and cut them in to circles. I placed them in the freezer for about fifteen minutes and baked them in the preheated oven for about twenty five minutes.

Turns out, today was a lucky day; they turned out quite fine... or maybe flat.

[image]

But, what about the runny batter? How could I avoid that in the future. I wasn't able to roll them in hands since it was sticky and gooey.

---

<sub>I already went through some posts here on stackexchange and they were quite informative.</sub>



<sub>[What kind of cookies can be shaped?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/31926/what-kind-of-cookies-can-be-shaped)

[What determines the shape-holding ability of cookies?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/880/what-determines-the-shape-holding-ability-of-cookies)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Typically, if adding flour doesn't help immediately, you can let the dough (batter?) sit covered, in the fridge for a while.

The chill will help to firm the dough up, and the extra time will allow the flour to fully hydrate.

If it's still not workable after that point, put it onto either plastic wrap or waxed paper, and roll it into a log, twisting the ends, then freeze the log.  You can then unwrap the log, and slice cookies off to be baked.

Comment: I said 'batter' because of the liquid like consistency that I got while making these.

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip the milk in the cookie recipe. 
If you want to add dairy, you can put dry milk or cream cheese. Milk isn't for cookies.